# How do I store integer values of EditText into SQLite Database [Android]

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am having trouble with storing integer value in SQLite database. 
Here are my codes.

My insert code of the Create_Events.java

```
Button btnCreate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
           calDB.open();
           long _id;
           EditText txtTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
          String title = txtTitle.getText().toString(); 
           EditText txtLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
           String location = txtLocation.getText().toString();
           EditText startTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
           String startTime = startTime.getText().toString();
          _id = calDB.insertEvent(title, location, 0, 0);

           calDB.close();

        }

});
```

CalendarAdapter.java (Database class)

```
package main.page;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class CalendarAdapter
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
    public static final String KEY_START = "starttime";
    public static final String KEY_END = "endtime";
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "anniversary";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "calendar";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table calendar(_id integer primary key autoincrement,"+
    "title text not null, location text not null, starttime integer, endtime integer);";

    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;


    public CalendarAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            try
            {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);    
            }catch(SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version "+oldVersion+" to "+newVersion+", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS calendar");
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public CalendarAdapter open() throws SQLException
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    public long insertEvent(String title, String location, int starttime, int endtime)
    {
       ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
       initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
       initialValues.put(KEY_LOCATION, location);
       initialValues.put(KEY_START, starttime);
       initialValues.put(KEY_END, endtime);
       return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

    }

    public boolean deleteEvent(long rowId)
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor getAllEvents()
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_START, KEY_END}, null, null, null, null, null);

    }

    public Cursor getEvent(long rowId) throws SQLException
    {
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_START, KEY_END}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(c != null)
        {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }

    public boolean updateEvent(long rowId, String title, String location, int starttime, int endtime)
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        args.put(KEY_LOCATION, location);
        args.put(KEY_START, starttime);
        args.put(KEY_END, endtime);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;

    }

}
```

As you can see above, I have managed to store text values from the EditText into the database successfully. So now I am trying to store the starttime(Integer) into database. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What's the problem exactly? It looks like you are always passing in 0 for `starttime`? How do you know it is not being stored?

Comment: No, I put 0 because I want to test whether the text values can be inserted into database. It is inserted into database but when I try to insert from editText the integer cannot be inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your real Question is "How to store a TIME or DATE in the SQLite database"?
You need to convert those into integer to store them, and convert back to whatever you for reading.
Please check chapter 1.2 of the SQLite documentation on that topic: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: If you want it easy, just convert your HH:MM into Minutes (Integer) and back using simple Java code ;)

Comment: Hi, I have visited the website that you have provided but I don't think it helped me cause as stated in the website we can store time in integer and that's what I did in my codes above. I only wanted to store the time into database, I don't want to convert the time or anything.

Comment: @CallMyName, your code does not have any means on converting the *String* you get from EditText into an *Integer*. You are actually storing "0" for both in your code: "calDB.insertEvent(title, location, 0, 0);". You did *not* store anything but 0 in database. So I have to assume you have problems converting a Time-string into Integer and back. As an example, "04:40" is *not* an Integer but a String.

Comment: As I have explained on the comment above, I don't intend to store 0. The 0 is just to test out whether it can be stored into the database. Anyways I already managed to store the time as String into the database. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: @CallMyName, so you decided not to store as integer. Thats ok if you don't need to sort and you don't check for valid entry. But that was not your question ;)
Can you please accept one of the answers, which all told you that you would need to convert a time-string to integer to store it as integer? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem storing integers - however time is not equivalent to integer.

You have 2 possibilities to store dates/time values. Either get the components and store each of the separately like year,month,day,minute,second or store it as a string - but you can't store date/time with ONE single integer.